# How do I add a second attachment to this VBA code for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, email

[Screen Shot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPah5.jpg)

Hi there, I'm an absolute novice at coding, and this is not my own work, but I was just looking to add a second attachment to this piece of code for sending out emails via excel. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value` adds the attachment. So the `msg.attachments.Add` is the command to add the attachment. And `sh.Range("E" & i).Value` is the argument of the command. Since `sh` is the workbook sheet, the `sh.Range("E" & i)` gets a range of cells in the worksheet and the `.Value` gets the values of these cells.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to alter it. It works!! Thanks for breaking it down for me!

Comment: Because I have less than 15 reputation points it doesn't seem to be letting me give you an up vote. Sorry about that.